# How to add an array of objects in a form data to do a POST request in js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, post, axios, form-data

i have a problem in adding an array of objects in a form data to do a POST request in Javascript. I have an API that will accept this format (an arrays of objects):

```
[
  {
    'var1': 'value',
    'var2': 'value',
    'var3': 'value'
   },
   {
    'var1': 'value',
    'var2': 'value',
    'var3': 'value'
   }
]
```

I am used to add values directly to the form data but this time i don´t know how to add values to the objects of the array and inserting them with the names of the form data. someone knows?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried please?

Comment: could you please brief more on this